# Is it possible to build a jQuery context menu with link item?

Tags: javascript, jquery, contextmenu

I am wondering, if it is possible to implement in the existing jQuery context menu ([link to jQuery custom context menu](http://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/demo/custom-command.html)) a link item, where you can right click on the link to get the default browser context menu.

This is my code so far:

```
    $('.cMenuCust').on('contextmenu', function(e){
           $('ul li:nth-child(3)').text((c > 100) ? 'tooMuch' : 'thatsOK');
           $('.context-menu-list').width(500);
    }); 

    $(function(){
        $.contextMenu.types.label = function(item, opt, root) {

            $('<span><a href="aLink">HTML</a><span>')
                .appendTo(this)
                .on('contextmenu', 'a', function(e) {

                    return true;
                });

            this.addClass('labels').on('contextmenu:focus', function(e) {

            }).on('contextmenu:blur', function(e) {

            });
        };

        $.contextMenu({
            selector: '.cMenuCust', 
            trigger: 'left',
            callback: function(key, options) {
                if (key === 'a') {
                    ...
                } else if (key === 'XLSX') {
                    ...
                } else if (key === 'CSV') {
                    ...
                }
            },
            items: {
                "title": {name: '{!cmTitel}', disabled: true},
                "sep1": "----------------",
                "XLS": {name: 'XLS'},
                label: {type: "label", customName: "Label", callback: function(){ return false; }, disabled: function(){ return (c > 10000); }},
                "CSV": {name: 'CSV'}                
            }
        });
    });
```

Do you have any idea how to get the default browser context menu, if I make a right click on the link item in the jQuery custom context menu ([link to jQuery custom context menu](http://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/demo/custom-command.html))?

Every hint is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is supported in [justContext.js](http://git.io/justContext.js), which doesn't even need jQuery. An example would be `<li data-action="sel_comment">Comment <a href="http://lal.de">selection</a></li>` which will look like [this](http://i.imgur.com/7fBreVM.png) and allow the browser to open the default context menu for that link.